Created a partition in the front of HDD with parted while it was mounted. What do I do so that my system doesn't crash on reboot?
I ran this command on /dev/sda1 when I meant to do something similar to /dev/sda2. /dev/sda1 was mounted at this time.
sudo parted -a opt /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
Warning: You requested a partition from 0.00B to 1000GB (sectors 0..1953525167).
The closest location we can manage is 17.4kB to 1048kB (sectors 34..2047).
Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No? yes                                                               
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance: 34s % 2048s != 0s
Ignore/Cancel? Ignore
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

The output of print is:
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 6      17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB                  primary
 1      1049kB  300MB   299MB   fat32                    boot, esp
 2      300MB   4347MB  4048MB  linux-swap(v1)           swap
 4      4347MB  124GB   120GB   ext4
 3      124GB   724GB   600GB   ext4
 5      724GB   1000GB  276GB   ext4

The output of fdisk -l /dev/sda is:
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 86AB55F1-52A1-4F8C-ACE9-1A7B4C4E9082

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     585727     583680   285M EFI System
/dev/sda2      585728    8491007    7905280   3.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda3   242864128 1414739967 1171875840 558.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4     8491008  242864127  234373120 111.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1414739968 1953523711  538783744 256.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6          34       2047       2014  1007K Linux filesystem

Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

This is the drive that contains my OS and everything. What do I do so that my reboot doesn't fail. Too afraid to turn off the machine right now.

Why do you think your reboot might fail?

Before rebooting make sure you backups are current. It looks like you created sda6 which is normally not allocated.

This partition shouldn't cause any harm, as long as existing partitions were untouched. What's the purpose of this partition? Are you trying to squeeze in a bios_grub partition? Something else? Consider giving your partitions proper names (or, no name at all if you don't need any). primary is a msdos partition concept not meaningful for GPT partition. If you didn't want this partition you can just delete it... just don't delete the wrong one

@ChrisDavies I have my sda6 partition infront of the boot partition according to fdisk output.

@frostschutz the partition was created by mistake. After I complete the backup, I will delete this as you suggested and try to reboot.

I wouldn't expect the boot to fail even though you've squeezed this last position in before the boot partition.
The boot partition, numbered one in your list and flagged boot, is the one that should be chosen at boot time:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 6      17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB                  primary
 1      1049kB  300MB   299MB   fat32                    boot, esp


If in doubt, just delete it (carefully!).
